# Maintain Bootstrap tab on Yii2 GridView page changing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gridview, tabs, yii2, pager

I have a page that has 5 bootstrap tabs. When I change pager on any tab, moves to the first tab occurs.
How to activate the tab which was to change the pager.

Entire page gets 5 dataProviders. Each like

```
$overallProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $overallArray,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 100,
            'pageParam' => 'overall-page',
            'params' => array_merge($_GET, ['#' => 'overall']),
        ],
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => ['rep'],
            'defaultOrder' => ['rep' => SORT_DESC],
            'sortParam' => 'overall-sort',
        ],
    ]);
```

In a view file created bootstrap tabs

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#overall" data-toggle="tab">Overall</a></li>
    <li><a href="#circuit" data-toggle="tab">Circuit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sprint" data-toggle="tab">Sprint</a></li>
    <li><a href="#drift" data-toggle="tab">Drag</a></li>
    <li><a href="#drag" data-toggle="tab">Drift</a></li>
</ul>
```

and each GridView widget looks like

```
<?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $overall,
            'layout' => "<div class='text-right'>{summary}</div>\n{items}\n<div class='text-center'>{pager}</div>",
            'pager' => [
                'options'=>['class'=>'pagination pagination-sm'],
                'hideOnSinglePage'=>true,
                'lastPageLabel'=>'>>',
                'firstPageLabel'=>'<<',
            ],
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                'username',
                'rep:decimal',
                'wins:decimal',
                'loses:decimal',
                'disc:decimal',
                'avg_opp_rating:decimal',
                'avg_opp_rep:decimal'
            ],
        ]) ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
      localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
   });
   var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
   if (lastTab) {
      $('[href=\"' + lastTab + '\"]').tab('show');
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfect for me and hope it helps someone else.

Comment: @iTPEMOP.  Mind upvoting if useful.

Comment: I can not yet. Rep score prevents.

Comment: @iTPEMOP. do it when have enough rep.

Comment: AMAZING AMAZING AMAZING - 3 hours looking and found thanks sooo much